# Laravel, call filter in filter

Tags: php, laravel, filter, routes

how i can call filter in filter using laravel?

i have this filter:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});
```

now i create another filter called admin and i want call auth filter in this:

```
Route::filter('admin', function(){
    #call auth filter

    #code    
});
```

it's possible do that?

Comment: Why would you do that? Did you consider attaching that filter the route the same way as auth filter?

Comment: i know this solution, but are not the best for my implementation...

because i have a lot of filter needed call by other filter, and some time i need to disable that dinamically, passing an arguments...

p.s. sorry for my bad english

Comment: For advanced filtering, you may wish to use a class instead of a Closure. Since filter classes are resolved out of the application IoC Container, you will be able to utilize dependency injection in these filters for greater testability. http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters at the bottom of section

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you have code that's called by a bunch of different filters, try writing a library class. If you want to call a bunch of different filters, it's best to chain them together on a route or use @delmadord's suggestion of a filter class. It looks like you're headed for a lot of pain if you set up a bunch of interrelated filters where A calls B, B calls C, etc. The dependencies are going to be awful to maintain.

Answer (score 5):

Using `callRouteFilter()` method in `Illuminate\Routing\RouteFiltererInterface` as @Dwight suggested:

```
Route::filter('admin', function ($route, $request) {
    if ($r = Route::callRouteFilter('auth', array(), $route, $request)) {
        return $r;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `callRouteFilter() method`.

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    Route::callRouteFilter('auth');
});
```

Comment: callRouteFilter requires the first 4 parameters. This would never work.